# Find and Split string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column in my table with data type varchar 
And that value is like a tag 
Example :

```
 <> e2=“69”  su=“58” fu=“55” <\>
```

I want search and find ‘su’ value and replace in that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/

In this case you will want to use something like

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(string, 'su="\d{2}"', 'su="value"')`